# object-rest-spread doesn't transform the spread syntax

Tags: redux, babeljs

Nothing seems to work to get webpack to recognize the spread operator.
I've also tried adding the 7.0.0-beta's for babel-core and object-rest-spread.

When I run, I get the message I need an appropriate loader to handle the file type. With an unexpected token on the place of the spread-operator. (see img)

[image: error msg]

This is my .babelrc:

```
{
    "plugins": [
        "syntax-dynamic-import",
        "transform-async-to-generator",
        "transform-es2015-destructuring",
        "transform-es2015-parameters",        
        "transform-object-rest-spread",
        ["react-intl", {
            "messagesDir": "./translations/messages/"
        }]],
    "presets": ["es2015", "react", "stage-0"]
  }
```

This is my webpack.config.js:

```
require('babel-polyfill');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index'
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.jsx$/, loader: 'babel-loader',  /*...*/},
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader!sass-loader' },
      { test: /\.(svg|png|wav)$/, loader: 'file-loader'},
      { test: /\.css$/, loader: 'style-loader!css-loader'},
      { test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000'},

    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, '/dist'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
```

This is my package.json:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^8.2.2",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-intl": "^2.2.0",
    "babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^6.18.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "es6-object-assign": "1.1.0",
```

The file where the error occurs:

```
const initialState = {
   sprites: {},
   stage: {}
};

const reducer = function (state, action) {
    if (typeof state === 'undefined') state = initialState;
    switch (action.type) {
    case UPDATE_TARGET_LIST:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            sprites: action.targets
                .filter(target => !target.isStage)
                .reduce(
                    (targets, target, listId) => Object.assign(
                        targets,
                        //error message spread operator not handled
                        {[target.id]: {order: listId, ***...target***}}
                    ),
                    {}
                ),
            stage: action.targets
                .filter(target => target.isStage)[0] || {}
        });
    case UPDATE_EDITING_TARGET:
        return Object.assign({}, state, {editingTarget: action.target});
    default:
        return state;
    }
};
```